# Turn quadrify maxscript into a scripted modifier

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

is it possible to turn the quadrify option from the graphite modeling ribbon into a scripted modifier?

the following two commands can be used in maxscript:

```
macros.run "PolyTools" "Quadrify"
PolyToolsModeling.Quadrify false false
```

i tried myself but i clearly lack the maxscript knowhow to get it done

Answer (score 0):

The only scripted modifier type that works interactively (i.e. not say extended edit poly modifier that breaks once the underlying topology changes) and can modify the mesh and not just deform it is SimpleMeshMod. In SimpleMeshMod, you get TriMesh to work with, not PolyMesh, so you cannot use the quadrify method. You could reimplement it as a TriMesh modifier if you made your own set of rules for hiding edges.